# Is it bad practice to return nullable types on error?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to read data from a Bluetooth OBDII dongle connected to my car. I have an OBDII helper class that is responsible for getting specific vehicle data. All of the methods I am writing return a nullable type; my thought was that when I consume this class, I can handle errors by checking for null. Here are two samples:

```
private byte?[] getPIDData(string pid)
    {
        string data = sendMessage(pid);
        string[] bytes = data.Split(' ');
        try
        {
            byte?[] convertedData = new byte?[bytes.Length - 2];
            for(int i = 2; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                convertedData[i - 2] = Convert.ToByte(bytes[i], 16);
            }
            return convertedData;
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

public double? GetEngineLoad()
    {
        byte?[] data = getPIDData("0104");
        if (data == null)
            return null;
        return (100.0 / 255.0) * (double)(data[0]);
    }
```

Is this bad practice/is there a better way to indicate errors when consuming these methods?

Comment: Why would you want to handle errors by checking for null? Just throw (or don't catch) exceptions. Then your consumer actually gets a *specific* error type, message, and stack trace.

Comment: How does checking for null "handle errors"?  It doesn't tell you anything about the error.

Comment: I suppose handling errors was the incorrect terminology. I'm going to be the only one consuming this class, so I was mostly going to use the null return value as an indication that something went wrong. However, even though I know I'm the only one consuming the class, I'd like to do things "by the book" so I can learn for future reference.

Comment: I do not agree with placing this question on hold. The title made it sound like an opinion-based question, but the question itself was very specific. I edited the title, and voted to re-open the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although returning nullable types is not a bad practice in general, it is definitely not an appropriate technique for reporting errors. The layer that consumes your API could catch the exception, and use a default value, log the error, etc.

If your code path throws an error, the code consuming your API should be handling it. Masking the error by returning a `null` makes for code that is harder to maintain, because exceptional conditions go unnoticed.

Another approach is using output parameters in an API that reports status instead of throwing an exception:

```
private bool TryGetPIDData(string pid, out byte[] res) {
    if (... success) {
        res = newValue;
        return true;
    } else {
        res = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're sort of a last resort. A byte array is inherently nullable so you can just return byte[]. Additionally, byte?[] isn't doing what you think it is. byte?[] is an array of nullable bytes, not a nullable array of bytes.

For the double, it's probably permissible. A lot of the try-parse style methods use an out parameter for the final data and the actual return value of the function is a boolean for success.

If an error is not generally expected, though, I would just let the exception get thrown or catch it and throw a specific exception for your API.

Also (100 / 255) is always 0.

Comment: The thing about `TryParse` is, the result doesn't indicate an exception, as in, *exceptional* situation. Failing to parse the value is a normal and expected result of that method. If you ran out of memory just as you called `TryParse`, it might raise OutOfMemoryException - it wouldn't just return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one writing and consuming all the code, and you know exactly what you're doing then it's ok, because no one else has to adapt to your programming style.....but I would never do this, especially when working with other programmers.

It's too easy to forget to check for null.  Null shouldn't indicate there is a problem, that is what throwing an exception is for.  Nulls don't force the stopping of execution of code not in a catch block, and the don't actually indicate that something is wrong, they just show the data isn't there. If you have to figure out where a problem is nulls, don't package up the stack trace to show you where the problem stemmed from.

C# is designed for exceptions to indicate there is problem.  Can you handle it another way?  Sure, but you're doing more work for the same or less benefit.  The only time I would ever consider not using exceptions is the case when I had to absolutely make sure that no exception was ever uncaught.  Honestly, even then I would consider taking a different approach than using nulls to indicate an error.  It's just too error prone, and too easy to make a mistake.